# Unable to download Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, download

I have tried several times during the last week to download the Android SDK from its officiel site ([1](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r12-linux_x86.tgz)) but couldn't. Is there someone who was able to download the SDK during the last week?

Comment: just tried it, and worked !! , what error are you getting ?

Comment: The browser (this time firefox) says : The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading. I'm now downloading the SDK using the link provided by Finn